# Does JNI requires ordering of arguments based on argument types

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to integrate some JNI code in my application that receives data from a web service and parse it in JNI layer from there I try to call a method defined in Java layer by passing some of the arguments received from the webservice. Following is the flow of functions and methods:

Variables defined for jclass and jmethodID:

```
    static jclass userInfo                      = NULL ;
    static jmethodID create_user_info = NULL ;
```

Struct defined at c layer to hold values

```
    struct User_Info {            
        long userId; // 1
        std::string firstName; // 2
        std::string lastName; // 3
        bool follow; // 4
    };
```

This function has problem. This function is called after receiving data from webservice, parsing it and creating struct User_Info

```
    static jobject createJavaObject(JNIEnv *env, const User_Info& info) {
        if(!userInfo){
            userInfo = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass("com/model/UserInfo"));
            assert(userInfo != NULL);
            create_user_info = env->GetStaticMethodID(userInfo, "createUserInfo", "("
                "I" // userId // 1
                "Ljava/lang/String;" // firstName // 2
                "Ljava/lang/String;" // lastName // 3
                "Z" // follow // 4
                ")Lcom/model/UserInfo;");
            assert(create_user_info != 0);
        }
        jstring firstName = cast<jstring>(env, info.first_name); // cast function just converts string to jstring 
        assert(firstName != NULL);
        jstring lastName = cast<jstring>(env, info.last_name);  // cast function just converts string to jstring 
        assert(lastName != NULL);
        
        // ISSUE IS WITH FOLLOWING CALL
        jobject res = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(userInfo, create_user_info,
                                                                  info.userId, // 1
                                                                  firstName, // 2
                                                                  lastName, // 3
                                                                  info.follow // 4 
                                                                  );

        env->DeleteLocalRef(firstName);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(lastName);
        return res;
    }
    
    
    // cast function:
    
    jstring cast<jstring, char const *>()(JNIEnv *env, char const *s)         {
        if (!s) return 0;
        jbyteArray bytes = env->NewByteArray(strlen(s));
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(bytes, 0, strlen(s), (jbyte*)s);
        jmethodID midStringCtor = env->GetMethodID(clsString, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V");
        jstring ret = (jstring)env->NewObject(clsString, midStringCtor, bytes, encoding);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(bytes);
        return ret;
    }
```

Java Method:

```
@Native
private static UserInfo createUserInfo(
                            int userId, // 1
                            String firstname, // 2
                            String lastname, // 3
                            boolean follow // 4
                        ) {
    UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
    info.userId = userId;
    info.firstname = firstname;
    info.lastname = lastname;
    info.follow = follow;
    return info;
}
```

Problem is that when I am running code, I am getting following error:

> > JNI ERROR (app bug): expected jboolean (0/1) but got value of 1048605 as argument 4 to com.model.UserInfo com.model.UserInfo.createUserInfo(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean)

## When I change the order of arguments in java method and jni functions and keep boolean 'follow' just after int 'userId', then issue does not occur.

My question is:

Does JNI require ordering of arguments based on their types
e.g. int parameter before long/boolean, or primitive parameters before objects etc.

If yes are there any references/docs that suggest it, if not then why my code works after changing arguments order?.

Comment: Hint: if you are 100% sure that your input from the webservice is OK, then: why are you talking about it here? What I mean is: try to reduce your question to the absolute "minimum". Things that happen before/after the problematic code but have nothing to do with the problem itself are just "waste" in that sense - just mentioning it makes people think about it; which doesn't help a bit (I am not saying you wrote a bad question, just pointing out that "being minimalistic" helps with getting good answers).

Comment: And side note: when talking about structs, the question is always how they are "packed" / "aligned". If I remember it correctly, unless you **specify** such things the compiler can do what it wants to do. In other words: maybe the compiler simply chooses to put the boolean as "second entry"; and thus the C++ compiler implicitly defines the order that you need.

Comment: 1. Yes, I am 100% sure about webservice. That might be irrelevant for this question. If its required, I will update my question.
2. Regarding struct, as I mentioned, I have just started with c++, I have no idea how to specifically inform compiler to take struct's values in the same order as defined. If you can provide more info about this, I can try at my side and see if its working or not.

Comment: For GCC (and possibly Clang) you would say `struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) User_Info { blah blah };`

Comment: I don't think passing a C++ bool directly to JNI is a good idea. Have you tried `info.follow ? JNI_TRUE : JNI_FALSE`?

Comment: To answer your question: no.

Comment: @Michael: I have tried with changing struct definition as you suggested. Still problem persists.

Comment: @user2543253: Yes, I tried above syntax earlier. Even I tried to pass JNI_FALSE/JNI_TRUE/0/1/ etc., in all cases same error was present.

Only scenario its working is when I move "follow" just below to "userId", as follows:
 create_user_info = env->GetStaticMethodID(userInfo, "createUserInfo", "("
  "I" // userId // 1
  "Z" // follow // 4
  "Ljava/lang/String;" // firstName // 2
  "Ljava/lang/String;" // lastName // 3
  ")Lcom/model/UserInfo;");

I change order in jni functions and java methods both. So order is same as above at all places and it works.

Comment: Don't know how Android would react to this but could it be that the stack becomes messed up by putting a (I am assuming 64 bit) long where a (32 bit) jint is expected? Compiler can't detect that because of varargs. Have you tried explicitly casting `userId` to `jint`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it required to keep some ordering of primitives and objects in JNI function arguments

This question is barely comprehensible. What is required is to keep the JNI method method declaration(s) in agreement with what is produced by running `javah` on the class containing the native methods.

```
static jclass userInfo                      = NULL ;
```

Here is a bug. It isn't valid to retain static references to `jobjects` or `jclasses` unless they are global or weak references.

Comment: Updated my question.

For second, I think code is correct. That reference is being used to only call the java method. The check is already there if its already not initialized. So each time there will be only one reference

Comment: The code is *not* correct, for the reason I have stated. See the discussion of global references in the JNI Specification. The `jclass` variable canot sensibly be static.